# How do I track down where I've been leaking IDisposable objects from?

Tags: c#

I've been debugging some code recently that was a bit memory leaky. It's a long running program that runs as a Windows service.

If you find a class wearing an `IDisposable` interface, it is telling you that some of the resources it uses are outside the abilities of the garbage collector to clean up for you.

The reason it is telling you this is that you, the user of this object, are now responsible for when these resources are cleaned up. Congratulations!

As a conscientious developer, you are nudged towards calling the `.Dispose()` method when you've finished with the object in order to release those unmanaged resources.

There is the nice `using()` pattern to help clean up these resources once they are finished with. Which just leaves finding which exact objects are causing the leakyness?

In order to aid tracking down these rogue unmanaged resources, is there any way to query what objects are loitering around waiting to be Disposed at any given point in time?

Answer (score 6):

There shouldn't be any cases where you don't want to call Dispose, but the compiler cannot tell you **where** you should call dispose.

Suppose you write a factory class which creates and returns disposable objects. Should the compiler bug you for not calling Dispose when the cleanup should be the responsibility of your callers?

Comment: That's fair enough, the Compiler won't help out because it can't possibly know where is the right place. In that case I'll update the question with "Is there any way to detect at the end of the program which objects are loitering around waiting to be Disposed?"

Comment: But the new question implies that there is a well-defined "end" of every program conceivable. Even for very simple, linear, batch-operation console programs, I would hesitate to point and say "..and here it ends."

Comment: Aha: I need to state my assumptions. You hit the nail on the head, I've been debugging a batch processing situation that was a little leaky and lead me to looking at where .Dispose() is being called. I'll re factor the question some more.

Answer (score 4):

IDisposable is more for making use of the using keyword.  It's not there to force you to call Dispose() - it's there to enable you to call it in a slick, non-obtrusive way:

```
class A : IDisposable {}

/// stuff

using(var a = new A()) {
  a.method1();
}
```

after you leave the using block, Dispose() is called for you.

Comment: This is by far the uselesst use of the var-keyword I've ever seen!

Comment: This is one of the contexts in which I find var the most usefult.

Answer (score 3):

"Is there any way to detect at the end of the program which objects are loitering around waiting to be Disposed?"

Well, if all goes well, at the end of the program the CLR will call all object's finalizers, which, if the IDisposable pattern was implemented properly, will call the Dispose() methods. So at the end, everything will be cleared up properly.

The problem is that if you have a long running program, chances are some of your IDiposable instances are locking some resources that shouldn't be locked. For cases like this, user code should use the using block or call Dispose() as soon as it is done with an object, but there's really no way for a anyone except the code author to know that.

Comment: Super: this was the problem I was dealing with, I wanted to fix my user code that should have been using the IDisposable interface and was hogging resources it shouldn't have been in a long running program. I think I distracted everyone by mentioning the compiler. I just wanted a tactic for tracking the non-tidyed-up items, I ended up using brute force: check everything manually. I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to call the Dispose method. Implementing the IDisposable interface is a reminder that your class probably is using resources such as a database connection, a file handle, that need to be closed, so GC is not enough.
The best practice AFAIK is to call Dispose or even better, put the object in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 1):

A good example is the .NET 2.0 Ping class, which runs asynchronously. Unless it throws an exception, you don't actually call Dispose until the callback method. Note that this example has some slightly weird casting due to the way Ping implements the IDisposable interface, but also inherits Dispose() (and only the former works as intended).

```
private void Refresh( Object sender, EventArgs args )
{
    Ping ping = null;

    try
    {
        ping = new Ping();
        ping.PingCompleted += PingComplete;
        ping.SendAsync( defaultHost, null );
    }
    catch ( Exception )
    {
        ( (IDisposable)ping ).Dispose();
        this.isAlive = false;
    }
}

private void PingComplete( Object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs args )
{
    this.isAlive = ( args.Error == null && args.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success );
    ( (IDisposable)sender ).Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask how you're certain that it's specifically objects which implement IDisposable?  In my experience the most-likely zombie objects are objects which have not properly had all their event handlers removed (thereby leaving a reference to them from another 'live' object and not qualifying them as unreachable during garbage collection).

There are tools which can help track these down by taking a snapshot of the managed heap and stacks and allowing you to see what objects are considered in-use at a given point in time.  A freebie is windbg using sos.dll; it'll take some googling for tutorials to show you the commands you need--but it works and it's free.  A more user-friendly (don't confused that with "simple") option is Red Gate's ANTS Profiler running in Memory Profiling mode--it's a slick tool.

Edit: Regarding the usefulness of calling Dispose--it provides a deterministic way to cleanup objects.  Garbage Collection only runs when your app has ran out of its allocated memory--it's an expensive task which basically stops your application from executing and looks at all objects in existance and builds a tree of "reachable" (in-use) objects, then cleans up the unreachable objects.  Manually cleaning up an object frees it before GC ever has to run.

Comment: To answer your question, when I tracked down and disposed of all of my IDisposable objects, my leakyness went away, I am now interested in how I might have more efficiently tracked them down.
That said thanks for the event's tip, no doubt I'll come across that one in the future, +1 for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the method creating the disposable object may be legitimately returning it as a value, that is, the compiler can't tell how the programming is intending to use it.

Comment: Or if the disposable object is set into a property/field or passed into any other method.  If the IDisposable object only exist within the lifetime of a single method than static analysis should be available.

Comment: And when I say 'should', I mean "ought to be, but isn't"

Answer (score 0):

What if the disposable object is created in one class/module (say a factory) and is handed off to a different class/module to be used for a while before being disposed of?  That use case should be OK, and the compiler shouldn't badger you about it.  I suspect that's why there's no compile-time warning---the compiler assumes the `Dispose` call is in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Determining when and where to call Dispose() is a very subjective thing, dependent on the nature of the program and how it uses disposable objects. Subjective problems are not something compilers are very good at. Instead, this is more a job for static analysis, which is the arena of tools like FxCop and StyleCop, or perhaps more advanced compilers like Spec#/Sing#. Static analysis uses rules to determine if subjective requirements, such as "Always ensure .Dispose() is called at some point.", are met.

I am honestly not sure if any static analyzers exist that are capable of checking whether .Dispose() is called. Even for static analysis as it exists today, that might be a bit on the too-subjective side of things. If you need a place to start looking, however, "Static Analysis for C#" is probably the best place.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I was barking up the wrong tree asking this of the compiler. I'm not sure static analysis is going to give me what I need either, I think what I'm asking for is runtime analysis, do you know any good runtime analysis tools?

Comment: I am not sure if there is anything like a runtime analysis tool. However, there are several decent .NET profilers that can trace your code and identify hotspots for you. They will not specifically target not calling .Dispose() (I don't think there is any analysis package that will identify that for you automatically.) However, tools like Ants Profiler and dotTrace will identify areas of excessive calls and runaway memory usage. That might help narrow down what code you need to look at to find missing calls to Dispose.